# Aloe barberae yellowing or dying?

Tags: diagnosis, watering, aloe

I have a 4-5 ft tall *Aloe barberae* that I planted on a hill about 2.5 months ago that has started yellowing in the past month and is looking pretty bad. I water 3 times per week. It gets sun the entire day and is inland in southern California. It might be worth noting that there used to be a large apple tree here. We have gopher problems that killed a lot of our plants but I wrapped the roots entirely with 1/4" mesh. I think the problem might be over watering. Thank you for your suggestions!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an *Aloe* to me. It looks stressed. It could be water stress (3x a week seems like a lot to me). It could be sun or something else. The good news is that the center part is still green and healthy looking.

Cut back on the water to once a week or less as we head into fall.

I don't think the wire is going to bother anything, but you should probably google *Aloe* and zinc to see if there are any interactions.

Comment: Yeah. I've never grown Aloes outdoors, but we had a plant that looked a lot like that indoors, and it did *not* like much water.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like sunburn to me. Also, and maybe I am wrong, but that does not look like an *Aloe* to me. I want to say that looks more like pineapple, but I have never seen a pineapple with that much leafless stem before.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I believe it’s called a tree aloe or aloe barberae. It makes sense for it to be getting too much exposure to the sun because the yellowing first started with the upward facing surfaces and the sun is very intense. I texted the nursery owner and he suggested reducing the altering to a deep water every 10 days.

Comment: Sunburn normally occurs on the parts closest to the sun, not the bottom of the plant. It's stressed from something. What type of soil is it planted in?